# Using PowerShell to export XML data to CSV. Childnodes with unique names

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, child-nodes

I've been stuck on this for awhile and cant figure out what I'm missing. I have an XML file which is an export of a camera server configuration. I'd like to match up the users with the cameras that they have permission to but am struggling to figure out how.

Here's a sample of the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExportedConfiguration verification="-11111111">
    <config timestamp="2017-05-30-08-35-21-533">
        <Users>
            <userlist>
                <user0>
                    <username>Smith, John</username>
                    <cameras>
                        <UserCamera-fd346f0a-362c-4171-b015-b3884db7d60f>
                            <cameraid>Inside-Camera1</cameraid>
                        </UserCamera-fd346f0a-362c-4171-b015-b3884db7d60f>
                    </cameras>
                </user0>
                <user1>
                    <username>Smith, Jane</username>
                    <cameras>
                        <UserCamera-07798ce7-b3fd-4cae-a0cd-339de22f38ab>
                            <cameraid>Outside-Camera1</cameraid>
                        </UserCamera-07798ce7-b3fd-4cae-a0cd-339de22f38ab>
                    </cameras>
                </user1>
              </userlist>
          </Users>
```

The problem is that everything falls under `<user#>` and the camera info falls under a random `<UserCamera-####>` node inside of `<user#>`. I think I need some sort of `foreach` loop based off the `<user#>` but not sure where to start.

[EDIT]
Here's what I have so far. When ran it just displays "cameraid" instead of the actual name:

```bsh
[xml]$file = Get-Content videoserver.xml
$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("//Users/userlist/*")
$o = New-Object Object
foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {
  $username = $xmlproperty.username
  $camera = $xmlProperties |
            Select-Xml -XPath "//cameraid" |
            Select-Object –ExpandProperty “node”

  [PSCustomObject]@{
    username = $username;
    Cameras  = $camera
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of Usernames and the UserCameraID, UserCamera they have access to?

Comment: google://powershell+xpath

Comment: what is the resulting csv? if you're just exporting a mapping user -> camera, then for each child of userlist, and for each child of cameras... no need for anything complicated - you wouldn't even need to use an xpath expression

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to export the username along and their <cameraid> underneath the UserCameraID.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$file.SelectNodes("//Users/userlist/*") | ForEach-Object {
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Username = $_.username
    Cameras  = $_.cameras.ChildNodes.cameraid -join ', '
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing I found in the XML just now is that every user has all the cameras listed but there's an additional node underneath UserCamera## which says if they have rights or not. The structure looks like this:

     <userrights>
         <access>yes</access>
     </userrights>

Is it possible to just display the ones that shows <access>yes</access> ?

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you meant there?